# How to remove automatically added <br class=“clear” > in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm creating one wordpress template. Required information added in wordpress header.php, footer.php and everything was fine. Then i added one page. But while viewing the page there was a small problem just above the footer. After checking i found following code creating all the problems

```
< br class="clear" >
```

But i didn't added that in page content. Somebody please tell me from where this thing came, and how to remove this?

Or atleast tell me some thing like where to check for problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: @BlakeWilson - actually i'm testing that in local pc. Any idea which file i should check ?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: @BlakeWilson - http://s9.postimg.org/b784xm9gf/up22.jpg  Please check above sample image,assume it as a sample view from footer part. In which red part is created due to `< br class="clear" >`

Comment: Does this happen on every page or just the single page or post?

Comment: @BlakeWilson - This exists in all pages

Comment: It'll be in the PHP template file(s) no doubt...but a quick fix could be `br.clear {display:none};`